# java while (resultset.next()) does not return all data in the same column

Tags: java, sql, resultset

i need your help. i want the resultset to fetch all data in member_code column, but it's only fetch 1 data. how to fetch all data in member_code using looping? here's my code:

```
    public String membercode() throws SQLException{
        String member="";
        
        String sql = "SELECT member_code FROM member";
            java.sql.Connection conn = (Connection) koneksi.config();
            java.sql.Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
            java.sql.ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            while(res.next()) { 

                 member = res.getString("member_code");
                 
            }
            return member;
}
```

Comment: you reassigne the value of res.getString("member_code") in loop. so member variable take the last value. try use List<String> instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assemble and return a "list". For example:

```
public List<String> membercode() throws SQLException{
    List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    String sql = "SELECT member_code FROM member";
        java.sql.Connection conn = (Connection) koneksi.config();
        java.sql.Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        while(res.next()) { 

             member = res.getString("member_code");
             members.add(member);
             
        }
        return members;
}
```